# Sometimes get ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::..,):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I added rest api for my existing application, but sometimes I get `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::ProductsController)` or `Puma caught this error: uninitialized constant Api::ProductsHelper` or the same problem with other controllers when calling this method from api. This does not happen every time, and I do not know who will crash next time.

[Files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTu53.png)

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  resources :products do
      get :is_new, :is_sale, :is_hit, on: :collection
  end

  resources :brands do
      get 'for_menu', on: :collection
  end
end
```

**ProductsController.rb**

```
class Api::ProductsController < ApiController
```

Comment: And how  `api_controller.rb` looks?

Comment: Same problem for me, it seems I have this random problem only when using workers -- I uncommented this line `workers ENV.fetch('WEB_CONCURRENCY') { 2 }` in `puma.rb` config file